# In SP 2013 daily email notification

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In SP 2013 daily email notification with number of items added and deleted in a document library.
For example let us consider in all the sub sites we have document library with common name "demo" but different items depends on the sub site. I want to have a daily email saying number of items added in (sub site) X=10 number of items deleted in (sub site) X =20 number of items added in Y=20 so on....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to write your custom logic with the help of SharePoint Timer job. 
It can iterate through all the subsites and list and then create a formatted report for emailing.
If you need to do this by designer then:

Create a loop which will run infinitely containing a pause of 1 day before executing again. Then do all the logic writing with the help of REST API

Comment: Could you please help me with the logic writing .. as am new to sharepoint finding things difficult...i would be really greatful for this help...

Comment: you need logic for timer job or Sharepoint workflow?

Comment: I need logic for timer job which can iterate through all the subsites and list and then create a formatted report for emailing.. Please help me out in this.